# How to turn a landscape pdf page to portrait

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework

I have a pdf document that contains several pages. 
Each page can has another orienatation as the other pages. 
We are using the Zend Framework in Version 1.12

Assuming page 1,2 and 4 are portrait and page 3 is landscape.

Target: all pages are in portrait mode.

```
        $pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($this->getFile());
        foreach ($pdf->pages as $index => $page) {
            /**
             * @var Zend_Pdf_Page $page
             * @var integer       $index
             */
            if (595 === $page->getHeight()) {
                $page->rotate(0, 0, deg2rad(90));
                $pdf->pages[$index] = $page;
            }
        }
        $pdf->save($this->getFile().'.new.pdf');
```

Result: same as before :/

What is wrong? Is it even possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the height is *exactly* 595 points?

Comment: nice point. but it does not matter. 
even with
 if ($page->getHeight() < $page->getWidth()) {
the pages are not turned to portrait

Comment: Test if the code does anything at all: remove the `if` so it should rotate all pages. If that doesn't work either, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: probably it does only rotates the canvas, not the page as it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I did it with Java :)

```
    try {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(filePath);
        List allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
            PDRectangle mediaBox = page.getMediaBox();
            if (mediaBox.getWidth() > mediaBox.getHeight()) {
                page.setRotation(90);
            }
        }
        String output = filePath + ".new.pdf";
        doc.save(output);
        doc.close();
        System.out.println("wrote output to " + output);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (COSVisitorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox